# Can't change specific color in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

It's the color that the background of a word or variable that highlights it's occurrences in the rest of the code. This is what my editor looks like. [Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcDdR.png)

I've customized it a little bit but whenever I'm typing on something the white background is jarring and makes it hard to read. How do I change it to a darker color?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors;
And change the value on the "Selection Background color"

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it. I think I didn't ask my question properly so let me reformat it real quick.